# Is this grammar in Chomsky Normal Form?

Tags: formal-languages, context-free

This was the initial CFG (starting symbol is I):

```
I → aAB
A → BAb | ε | B
B → a | b | CD
C → ba
D → DD
```

And this its CNF:

```
X → a
X'→ b
I → XY
Y → AB | a | b | X'X
Y'→ BA | a | b | X'X
A → Y'X' | a | b | X'X
B → a | b | X'X
```

Is it correct?

Comment: We discourage "please check whether my answer is correct" questions, as only "yes/no" answers are possible, which won't help you or future visitors. See [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/597/) and [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/519/). Can you edit your post to ask about a specific conceptual issue you're uncertain about? As a rule of thumb, a good conceptual question should be useful even to someone who isn't looking at the problem you happen to be working on. If you just need someone to check your work, you might seek out a friend, classmate, or teacher.

Comment: D is useless in the original grammar as presented. Is that correct or is there a missing production.

Comment: Your title doesn't match your question.